# Create clock hand coordinates based off center point

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am trying to create clock hand coordinates based off the center point (I have the center point already). Here is the code I have so far:

What I have on my VB.NET form:

http://i58.tinypic.com/3ehwl.png

```
Private Sub CreateClockPoints(ByVal centerPt As VISIPoint)
        Dim vPtD As New VISIPoint

        If rbn1.Checked Then
            vPtD.Put(centerPt.X, centerPt.Y + Util.convertVal(1.5, 1, 2), centerPt.Z)
        ElseIf rbn2.Checked Then
            vPtD.Put(centerPt.X, centerPt.Y, centerPt.Z)
        ElseIf rbn3.Checked Then
            vPtD.Put(centerPt.X, centerPt.Y, centerPt.Z)
        ElseIf rbn4.Checked Then
            vPtD.Put(centerPt.X + Util.convertVal(1.5, 1, 2), centerPt.Y, centerPt.Z)
        ElseIf rbn5.Checked Then
            vPtD.Put(centerPt.X, centerPt.Y, centerPt.Z)
        ElseIf rbn6.Checked Then
            vPtD.Put(centerPt.X, centerPt.Y, centerPt.Z)
        ElseIf rbn7.Checked Then
            vPtD.Put(centerPt.X, centerPt.Y - Util.convertVal(1.5, 1, 2), centerPt.Z)
        ElseIf rbn8.Checked Then
            vPtD.Put(centerPt.X, centerPt.Y, centerPt.Z)
        ElseIf rbn9.Checked Then
            vPtD.Put(centerPt.X, centerPt.Y, centerPt.Z)
        ElseIf rbn10.Checked Then
            vPtD.Put(centerPt.X - Util.convertVal(1.5, 1, 2), centerPt.Y, centerPt.Z)
        ElseIf rbn11.Checked Then
            vPtD.Put(centerPt.X, centerPt.Y, centerPt.Z)
        ElseIf rbn12.Checked Then
            vPtD.Put(centerPt.X, centerPt.Y, centerPt.Z)
        End If

    End Sub
```

The distance from the center to the clock point must be 1.5.

As you can see I already have 1, 4, 7, and 10 figured out. I am not sure what the formula would be for 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 11, and 12. Let me know if you want any additional information, thanks.

Comment: what do you know about trigonometry? If you have the angle then it's a matter of calculating `X = length * sin(angle) + centerPt.X; Y = length * cos(angle) + centerPt.Y;` Obvious in 3D it's a bit more complicated (but the idea is the same): [wiki to the rescue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_(mathematics)#Three_dimensions)

Comment: @CarstenKönig Thanks so much, this is what I was looking for. Not familiar enough with math to know this off the top of my head but with the right direction I'm all set. Thanks again, you should make this an answer so you get credit.

Comment: no problem - the other answers are the same - I got all the rep I need (no more milestones to get and I will never be a J. Skeet anyways) - just pick the best answer (for you) and accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a homework assignment, so I'll spoilerize some of the answers, and I won't give you actual code.

Let's assume you've taken trigonometry and know the formula for a [unit circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle).

The formulae you want for offset x and y can be determined from the angle of the clock hand (which we'll call `theta`).  Since there are 12 hours, and 360 degrees in a circle, `theta = hours * 360 / 12`.  Then you can get:

> x = 1.5 * sin (theta)

and

> y = -1.5 * cos (theta)

Comment: Be sure, when using the .Net Trig functions to convert your angles to radians.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway, I deliberately specified that I'm not giving real code, but yes, that's an important note for a .NET implementation.

Comment: Yo Eric I tried to upvote this but it says I don't have enough reputation. Thanks so much, this and the comment before is what I was looking for!

Comment: Sorry I meant to direct that message to you @EricHughes

Comment: @EricHughes This comment has nothing to do with the actual question or your answer, but I wanted to give you a +1 for awesomeness on the use of `>!` in your answer. I had no idea that SO would do that.

Answer (score 0):

A normal clock should have 12 on the top and 6 on the bottom.

To get the coordinates for your pixel you can use a rotation [matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) to rotate a vector from 0° to 359°

**! this is no real vb.net code!**

```
function rotate(ByVal p as Point2D,ByVal angle as Single) as Point2D
    Single X = p.X * cos(angle) - p.Y * sin(angle)
    Single Y = p.X * sin(angle) + p.Y * cos(angle)
    return new Point2D(X,Y)
end function
```

Be careful, the rotation matrix will rotate anticlockwise so you should negate the angle. You should create some kind of mapping between angle in deg and your time

this can be done by div your time by 12 and mult it with 360°

```
function getAngleForTime(ByVal time as Integer) as Single
    Dim scale = time / 12
    return scale * 360
end function
```

this function makes 12:00 to 360° and 3:00 to 90°

Now you can rotate a vector with length 1.5:

```
Dim time as Integer = 4
Dim angle as Single = getAngleForTime(time)
Dim p as new Point2D(1.5,0)
Dim p_r as Point2D = rotate(p, -angle) 'use negative angle here !
```

Now you have a rotated vector. To get the final coordinates for your point, you have to add the coordinates from your center point to the vector:

```
Dim final_point as Point2D
final_point.X = p_r.X + center_point.X
final_point.Y = p_r.Y + center_point.Y
```

I hope this helps you. I have no visual studio to test this code. Please adapt this code to your example. Sorry for my bad endlish.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use some basic Trig to determine the X,Y coordinates.  Given that there are 12 clock points, you can use this function to determine the X,Y coordinate for any point on the clock.  Note that this will return the X,Y coordinate for the standard Cartesian plane.  You will have to convert to the .Net coordinate system for drawing.

```
'Returns the X,Y coordinate of a point on a clock given a center point and radius.  
'Clock point 0 = 12:00, 1 = 1:00, etc.
Private Function getClockPoint(center As PointF, radius As Double, clockPoint As Integer) As PointF
    Dim angle As Double = clockPoint * (2.0 * Math.PI) / 12.0

    Dim x As Single = center.X + CSng(radius * Math.Sin(angle))
    Dim y As Single = center.Y + CSng(radius * Math.Cos(angle))

    Return New PointF(x, y)
End Function
```